# Divide Average of a Category by Average of the all categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database that I essentially want to take the average of a group and divide by the average of the total. For example:

```
Fruit        Number_of_Seeds
Rasp            50
Rasp            65
Straw           200
Blue            20
Straw           250
```

So I want to get something of the form:

```
Fruit        Avg Seeds of Fruit / Avg of All Fruits 
Rasp                  =((50+65)/2)/((50+65+200+20+250)/5)     
Straw
Blue
```

I already have code to get the average seeds for fruit but how would I incorporate the denominator if I already have a group by Fruit statement?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: what is the dbms being used?

Comment: SQL Server is the dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to add the .0 to gain precision, AND select DISTINCT

```
Declare @YourTable table (Fruit varchar(50),Number_of_Seeds int)
Insert into @YourTable values
('Rasp',            50),
('Rasp',            65),
('Straw',          200),
('Blue',            20),
('Straw',           250)

Select Distinct Fruit
      ,AvgSeed= Avg(Number_of_Seeds+.0) over (Partition By Fruit)/Avg(Number_of_Seeds+.0) over ()
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Fruit   AvgSeed
Blue    0.170940
Rasp    0.491452
Straw   1.923076
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select fruit, avg(1.0*num_seeds) / (select avg(1.0*num_seeds) from tablename)
from tablename
group by fruit
```

or using window function

```
select fruit, avg(1.0*num_seeds) over(partition by fruit) / avg(1.0*num_seeds) over()
from tablename
```